# Do we ever need more than one pthread barrier? For example?

Tags: pthreads, barrier

Barriers seem to be used quite often in Pthreads. Pthreads provides pthread_barrier_init() primitive to help create new barriers.

```
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html
```

However, in my own experience, I haven't seen any *real-world programs that use more than one barrier? I googled and saw this topic http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/when-do-you-need-more-than-1-pthread-barrier-variable-752164/. However, that topic didn't introduce any example programs that real need more than 1 barrier.

**So, I am wondering whether we ever need more than one barrier in a program? Any real-world example?**

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: You mean it's enough one barrier object in real-world program? For instance, when program has two independent parallelized task, two barrier objects are required naively.

Comment: You are totally right. It's conceptually ok, but practically so far I am not aware of any such programs. Could you please indicate some real world examples that actually use more than 1 barrier in that way?